# Link below the footer removal

Tags: links, footer

[image]i am just starting out with wordpress ,have a hosting account and using wordpress there..In every page,below the footer there is a link that takes people to donate to doctors without borders. I need that link removed and i can't locate anywhere..i tried in wp editor,in cpanel..no luck..if i inspect the source from a webpage i see: 
tried to copy from there but it just shows text here..the site is thisisyours.space

Comment: not clear your question

Comment: please add screenshot your page

Comment: From an earlier edit it looked like you tried to include some HTML which will have got removed by the editor. When you want to insert code like that select it with the mouse and press Ctrl-K to format as code. Then if you look below at the preview you should see it's been formatted correctly.

Comment: add this css class your style.css file .footlinks{display:none !important;}

Comment: second think edit this page or post and remove this line

Comment: @vikrant zilpe Thank you !i added the css class and  it worked !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

add this css class your style.css file

```
.footlinks{display:none !important;}
```